# script execution time during grouping

Tags: php

```
<?php

$urls = array(
    'us/1',
    'us/2',
    'gb/1',
    'gb/2',
    'de/1',
    'de/2',
);

$current_country = '';
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $sleep_sec = rand(1, 3);
    printf('Proccessed url <b>%s</b> in %s sec%s', strtoupper($url), $sleep_sec, '<br/>');

    $country = substr($url, 0, 2);
    if ($current_country !== $country) {
        $start_at = microtime(true);
        $end_at = microtime(true) - $start_at;

        $logs[] = sprintf('Proccessed country <b>%s</b> in %s sec', strtoupper($country), $end_at);
    }
    $current_country = $country;

    sleep($sleep_sec);
}

echo str_repeat('<br>', 2);

foreach($logs as $log) {
    echo $log;
    echo '<br>';
}
```

**Now result is:**

Proccessed url **US/1** in 2 sec 
Proccessed url **US/2** in 2 sec 
Proccessed url **GB/1** in 1 sec 
Proccessed url **GB/2** in 2 sec 
Proccessed url **DE/1** in 3 sec 
Proccessed url **DE/2** in 2 sec 

Proccessed country **US** in 1.9073486328125E-6 sec
Proccessed country **GB** in 2.1457672119141E-6 sec
Proccessed country **DE** in 5.0067901611328E-6 sec

**Expected result:**

Proccessed country **US** in 4 sec
Proccessed country **GB** in 3 sec
Proccessed country **DE** in 5 sec

How to count correct execution time for each country ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your lines of code around so they actually make sense:

```
$start_at = microtime(true);
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $sleep_sec = rand(1, 3);
    sleep($sleep_sec);
    printf('Proccessed url <b>%s</b> in %s sec%s', strtoupper($url), $sleep_sec, '<br/>');

    $country = substr($url, 0, 2);
    $current_country = $country;
    if ($current_country !== $country) {
        $end_at = microtime(true) - $start_at;
        $logs[] = sprintf('Proccessed country <b>%s</b> in %s sec', strtoupper($country), $end_at);
        $start_at = microtime(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Aight, that was the point, I started out typing what should be placed where, but in the end, I figured actually placing all lines at their correct location would be easier ;)